# Decode Postgres bytea column (containing an image) to binary format using R

Tags: r, postgresql, image, encode

I have images stored in a postgres bytea column.
I am using the following code to retrieve the images.

```
library('RODBC')
library('tidyverse')
library('base64enc')

# get the data from the database
rc <- odbcConnect('odk_prod')
img_tbl <- sqlQuery(rc, 'select * from odk_prod."GRAVEL_ROADS_1_3_GRAVEL_PHOTO_BLB"')

# create the file for writing and squirt the 1's and 0's in it
to.write = file("img.jpg","wb")
writeBin( (unlist(img_tbl[1,'VALUE'])), to.write)
close(to.write)
```

When I open the file I create (img.jpg), it is "corrupted", because the bytea column returns hex encoded data.

What function can I use to encode my image data to binary and retrieve my image?